# HttpHandler in IIS7 and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7, web-config, httphandler

I'm trying to run an httphandler (ashx) in a asp.net 4 website.

When I call it from Visual Studio integrated server, it returns a 404 error.

It works if I call it on the site configured into the local IIS.

Someone could help?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using ASP.NET MVC, or System.Web.Routing?

Do you have something like

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}");
```

in your `RegisterRoutes()` function in your `HttpApplication` instance?

One thing to keep in mind is that the Visual Studio server thingie runs all requests through the managed pipeline.

Is the `httpHandler` added to the `system.web` section of the `Web.config` file? (In IIS7, this goes under the `system.webServer` section, but I am not sure if newer versions of Cassini will look there.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Classic asp.net site, no MVC, no Routing.
In the web.config file I havve this:

<system.webServer>
 <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<handlers>
 <add name="myAshx" path="myAshx.ashx" verb="GET" type="myAshx" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>

Comment: Try adding an appropriate httpHandler under the old <system.web><httpHandlers> section. Cassini predates IIS7, I doubt that they updated it to look in the IIS7 <system.webServer> section. Could be wrong on this, though, but worth a shot.

Comment: It works!! Thanks. Just a question, when I deploy it, I don't need the section in the System.Web right ?

Comment: No, but it doesn't hurt to leave it there. IIS6 & Cassini look at system.web/httpHandlers, and IIS7 looks at system.webServer/handlers. This is because the IIS team yells "Do over!" every few years, so we repeat ourselves if we need to support the multiple versions in our applications.